# Trying to claim rewards on bonkrewards.com - Program Error: "Instruction #1 Failed"

Tags: failed, instruction

When I try to claim rewards on bonkrewards.com I get this result:

```
Program Error: "Instruction #1 Failed"
```

Program log:

```
#1 Unknown program instruction
 > Program log: Instruction: ClaimAll
 > Invoking Token Program
  > Program log: Instruction: Transfer
  > Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData
  > Program Token Program  consumed 2800 of 186973 compute units
  > Program returned error: invalid account data for instruction
 > Program STAKEkKzbdeKkqzKpLkNQD3SUuLgshDKCD7U8duxAbB  consumed 15827 of 200000 compute units
```

This is the tx: https://solscan.io/tx/K83AmqJfK8iDC3jbT76vhayMa8cZZN3BN8KmH6ZQbspehu3FYK5wWbS3jYCkqruvrSfVU4rT1aajn2NBJUzuGvS

Any idea what's causing this problem and what I can do?